# Program a Google Drive account directly into the application?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Rather than asking the user to select a Google account for connecting to Google Drive, can I store a single Google Drive account into the application for use across all installations of the application? The app wouldn't ask the user for an account but just connect to Google Drive using the account stored in it and be able to immediately start uploading/downloading. Is it possible for the application to have it's own G account or is it absolute that the user has to select a G account?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea to me. How would something like that scale to hundreds of users? You would use up your storage relatively fast with a lot of users

Comment: @swerly It's meant for a private application to which only a small number of people would be able to use.